# Scan function with m modifier not working as intended

Tags: parsing, sas, scanning

The scan function does not seem to work as I want it.

```
data test;
do i=1 to 5;
text="ABC¤¤ABC¤ABC¤ABC";
scan = scan(text,i,"¤","m");
output;
end;
run;
```

Results:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCxK9.png)

It is working for i=2 but I don't understand why i=3 and i=4 are blank...
What I want is scan=blank for only i=2 where there is a consecutive delimiter.

However, if my delimiter is a comma, it works...

```
data test;
do i=1 to 5;
text="ABC,,ABC,ABC,ABC";
scan = scan(text,i,",","m");
output;
end;
run;
```

Results:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2gRe.png)

What am I doing wrong ???

Comment: What is the hex code for that character?

Comment: No idea. Unicode is U+00A4. See more here https://www.compart.com/fr/unicode/U+00A4

Comment: SCAN() does not understand mult-byte characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SAS session is using unicode.  So that symbol you are trying to use requires more than one byte.  The SCAN() function will treat that as two separate delimiter characters. So the M modifier will then see the two differnt bytes next to each other as representing a missing value.

Use the KSCAN() function instead.

To use the M modifier you will need to use KSCANX() function. (I have asked SAS to update the documentation of these three functions so they reference each other.)

You could try eplacing the two-byte character with some single byte character so that you can use the SCAN() function but then you could also have issues with the delimiter being seen as one of the bytes in some other multi-byte character in the string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I replaced it with "|" to avoid this error. Is there a custom delimiter that only SAS has to be sure people don't encounter any errors ?

Answer (score 2):

To go into more detail on Tom's (correct) answer, SAS is a language that existed well before Unicode.  It maintains backwards compatibility, for the most part, and that means that many SAS functions aren't compatible with Unicode.

SAS has a page, [Internationalization Compatibility with SAS String functions](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=nlsref&docsetTarget=p1pca7vwjjwucin178l8qddjn0gi.htm&locale=en), which goes into detail as which functions are compatible with non-Single Byte Character Sets (for example, UTF-8, a Multi-Byte Character Set).

Functions that are listed as "I18N Level 0" (I18N is short for Internationalization - 18 characters between the I and the last n) are not compatible with non-single byte character sets. SCAN is one of those functions. "I18N Level 1" might work or might not, and "I18N Level 2" are designed to work with MBCSs, like UTF-8.

For the most part, the functions designed with UTF-8 in mind start with 'k' and are otherwise similar to the base SAS functions.  However, in a few cases they had to make variants.

For your use, [`kscanx`](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=nlsref&docsetTarget=n1igdmpa0ykbznn1dnwdgqbi32tg.htm&locale=en#n0433ivnziks6hn1opw85c1tsbbv) is the function you'll want.  That allows the `m` modifier to be used.

It's still possible you'll have issues, if your SAS session and your SAS data are not in the exact same encoding.  Consider the `UNICODE` or `UNICODEC` functions, or the `KCVT` function, to modify the character set of one or the other to match.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

I ran the program

```
data test;
do i=1 to 5;
text="ABC¤¤ABC¤ABC¤ABC";
scan = scan(text,i,"¤","m");
output;
end;
run;
```

and got this

[image]

Comment: What is your SAS version?  Mine is SYSVLONG4=9.04.01M6P11072018.

Comment: 9.04.01M3P062414